# Separation of variables for the fractional laplacian

Tags: laplacian, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider the fractional Laplacian of $u\in H^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denoted as $(-\Delta)^s u$ with $s\in (0,1)$. I know that in general for the usual Laplacian we can write $\Delta = \Delta_r + r^{-2}\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ where $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is the $n-1$ dimensional sphere and $r$ is the radial part. Do we have a similar decomposition for the fractional Laplacian as well?

Comment: Perhaps the non-locality of this operator prevents us from having such a decomposition

Comment: For those who are interested, representations of the fractional Laplacian for radially-symmetric functions can be found in [Garofalo, Fractional thoughts; Section 7] and in [Ferrari, Verbitsky, Radial fractional Laplace operators and Hessian inequalities; Theorem 1.1].